# RS485 Arduino Communication Issue

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial, rs485, modbus

Friends, I am trying to achieve half duplex communication between two Arduinos using RS485 Protocol. The hardware I am using is a MAX485 module and an Arduino Uno. I am using the SoftwareSerial library for Arduino, but I am not be able to transmit data from sender to receiver. The length of the wire between MAX485 modules is 1 meter.

My question is, what wrong I am doing here, please guide me.

The code:

**SenderDevice**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 7);

String strCmd;
int counter;

void setup()
{

 Serial.begin(9600);
 mySerial.begin(9600);

 pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
 counter = 0;

}

void loop()
{

  counter++;
  strCmd = "Counter" + String(counter) + "$";
  Serial.println("Sending " + strCmd);
  mySerial.print(strCmd);

  delay(10);
  mySerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();
  memset(&strCmd, 0, sizeof(strCmd));
  delay(2000);

}
```

**ReceiverDevice**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 7);

String strCmd;

void setup()
{

 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("ready");

 pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(5, LOW);
 mySerial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

   while (mySerial.available() > 0) {

        char c = mySerial.read();
        if (c == '$') {

           Serial.println("Received " + strCmd);
           memset(&strCmd, 0, sizeof(strCmd));

        } else {

          strCmd = strCmd + c;

        }

  }

}
```

**My Wire Connections are :**

```
(Both Sender & Receiver Device)
Arduino Uno 6 -> Max485 RO
Arduino Uno 7 -> Max485 DI
Arduino Uno 5 -> Max485 DE
Arduino Uno 5 -> Max485 RE
Arduino Uno 5V -> Max485 VCC
Arduino Uno GND -> Max485 GND

Sender Max485 A -> Receiver Max485 A
Sender Max485 B -> Receiver Max485 B
```

Comment: I have quite bad experience with using the software library using MIDI which has a very low baudrate; I advise to at least try with the hardware UART (RX/TX) to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Do you have GND connected between sender and receiver?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers : I am already using the hardware UART for someother reasons.

Comment: @Matej : I have tried connection the ground of both devices too, But it did not work.
In real time my application is going to be 15 meters away.

Comment: I only said to try it, so you know if the problem is in the library/software; if it works with a hardware serial, than at least you know your code is ok.

Comment: @Michael : my general rx-tx communication is working. After searching a lot on web i have found this code. Actually modified the example code of the library.

Comment: @javabee I never had problem with it and I don't see anything wrong with your code or wiring. Do you have another modules to test it?

Comment: @javabee "I have tried connection the ground of both devices too" you absolutely MUST connect ground of both devices. Senders and receivers data lines are flipped? And do you have an oszilloscope to monitor the transfer? Timing is always critical in proticols that don't use a clock line

Comment: @Matej : I purchased new Arduinos and Max485 yestrday. Its not also working too.
I don't know why this simple piece of code is not working. Please someone help me.

Comment: @SimSon : I dont have oszilloscope. what other way can you suggest to debug.

Comment: @javabee So modules are all right. You can try this code:   https://github.com/matrn/RS485protocol    it worked for me but I am not sure if problem is in code. Also as Sim Son wrote you must have gnd of both devices connected.